# Jinja not Translating Variables in Airflow DAGs

Tags: python, apache-spark, jinja2, airflow

I have an Airflow instance that does not translate Jinja variables.  I have this code in my DAG.

```
print 'execution date is: ', ' {{ ds }} '
```

The above variable is printed literally.

```
INFO - Subtask: execution date is:   {{ ds }}
```

Jinja2 is installed via pip (I am using Python 2.7).  PYTHONPATH are set correctly because an import statement from the jinja module is processed in the same DAG without a problem.

```
from jinja2 import Environment
```

I am using airflow 1.8.0.

I am missing something but I am running out of clues.

Comment: Don't know about Airflow, but I suppose that the rendering of the template is done in the `templated_command` in `BashOperator`.  As far as I can see from your code, those are plain strings printed and they aren't supposed to be rendered by jinja.

Comment: Thanks, @jgmh.  The `templated_command` in the Airflow tutorial is just a variable name.  it gets assigned later on to `bash_command`.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed.  Silly me; I had a `format()` that prevented Jinja from taking over.

```
"{path} {{ ds }} ".format(path="the/path/to/spark/code")
```